# WP7 Microsoft Advertising AdControl disappears and throws exceptions

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads

I am having trouble implementing the AdControl into my Silverlight WP7 application. Yesterday I registered at PubCenter and setup a new Windows Phone 7 application. PubCenter tells me that it is approved and gives me my application Id. For this post let's say the application Id is `abc-123`. Next, I created an Ad unit named "Developer" (my app is for developers).

I chose two categories (Technology & Computing - All, Education - Graduate School). I selected "6:1 ratio Large banner (216*36)" as my ad unit format. I am not sure about the ad format but after I saved it, I have not been able to change it. For this post let's say the Ad unit Id is `55555`.

I installed the SDK for Microsoft Advertising then added the reference `Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI` to my phone project.

I added the AdControl to one of my xaml pages:

```
<UI:AdControl ApplicationId="abc-123" AdUnitId="55555" AdModel="Contextual"></UI:AdControl>
```

with the namespace:

```
xmlns:UI="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;assembly=Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI"
```

In the code behind of the page I have the control on I have set the test mode just as the tutorials suggest:

```
using Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;
...
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AdControl.TestMode = true;
}
```

When I run the application and navigate to the page, I see the gray border of the AdControl for just a moment, then the AdControl disappears. No runtime error or anything that might stop execution. If I look at the output window I can see the control failing:

> 'taskhost.exe' (Managed): Loaded
>   '\Applications\Install\D9123383-1522-4DCC-A270-AD0E7B642996\Install\Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll'
>   'taskhost.exe' (Managed): Loaded
>   '\Applications\Install\D9123383-1522-4DCC-A270-AD0E7B642996\Install\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.dll'
>   'taskhost.exe' (Managed): Loaded
>   'System.Windows.debug.resources.dll' A
>   first chance exception of type
>   'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.dll A first chance
>   exception of type
>   'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.dll A first chance
>   exception of type
>   'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll

I have tried deploying to a developer device and setting test mode to false with the same result. I even tried the test parameters that I have read about on the web:

```
<UI:AdControl ApplicationId="test_client" AdUnitId="Image480_80" AdModel="Contextual"></UI:AdControl>
```

This also results in the control disappearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steve,

I think I see the issue. You're setting `AdControl.TestMode = true` in the `MainPage` constructor, which is too late in the app's launch cycle. Try moving that line to the constructor of your `App.xaml.cs` codebehind file. The `App` class loads before anything else, setting the mode there ensures that it happens early enough.

Not 100 percent sure on the rationale here, but my guess is that `TestMode` needs to be set before the control is rendered. The control tree has already finished rendering by the time the `MainPage`'s `InitializeComponent` method completes.

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I added to the app constructor and it works. Thanks.

Comment: The testmode property is not there anymore. Not sure if you updated the SDK recently.